# Bootstrap Sidebar only opens after being clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have just made a simple hamburger style sidebar however i can't seem to get it to work when i click on the hamburger icon it turns to an X like it should but the menu only appears briefly when i click the close button is there a reason for this and is there a way i can get JUST the close button to actually be in the sidebar with the z-index or something?

Codeply link:
https://www.codeply.com/p/R4UGFDIGuw

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>.sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar { 
      display: none; 
    } 


      .animated-icon {
      width: 30px;
      height: 20px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
      transition: .5s ease-in-out;
      cursor: pointer;
      }

      .animated-icon span {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 3px;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 9px;
      opacity: 1;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      }

      .animated-icon span {
      background: #f3e5f5;
      }

      .animated-icon span:nth-child(1) {
      top: 0px;
      -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
      -moz-transform-origin: left center;
      -o-transform-origin: left center;
      transform-origin: left center;
      }

      .animated-icon span:nth-child(2) {
      top: 10px;
      -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
      -moz-transform-origin: left center;
      -o-transform-origin: left center;
      transform-origin: left center;
      }

      .animated-icon span:nth-child(3) {
      top: 20px;
      -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
      -moz-transform-origin: left center;
      -o-transform-origin: left center;
      transform-origin: left center;
      }

      .animated-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      top: 0px;
      left: 8px;
      }

      .animated-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
      width: 0%;
      opacity: 0;
      }

      .animated-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      top: 21px;
      left: 8px;
      }</style>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>


<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">



  <!-- Collapse button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler hamburger-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent22" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent22" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="Nav()"><div class="animated-icon"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div></button>
  <!-- Navbar brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-right: 50%" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <!-- Collapsible content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent22">

    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto sidenav" id="mySidenav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Links -->

  </div>
  <!-- Collapsible content -->

</nav>
<!--/.Navbar-->

    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>function Nav() {
  if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width === "0px") {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    $('.animated-icon').toggleClass('open');
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
    $('.animated-icon').toggleClass('open');
  }
}</script>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Nav() {
  var width = document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width;
  if (width === "0px" || width == "") {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    $('.animated-icon').toggleClass('open');
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
    $('.animated-icon').toggleClass('open');
  }
}
```

**Why**
At first, `document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width` returns `''`

Comment: Okay that's weird because it worked fine before i added the fancy animation so i thought that it was something to do with that but okay that works and thanks